# need help in rephrasing 'duly' in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Newspapers across the political spectrum duly went into outrage mode.

I found this sentence on the internet and am afraid there is no further context on that. according to [thefreedictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/), duly has 2 meanings which are:

1. In a proper manner.
2. At the expected time.

But I don't see both 2 meanings fit in this sentence and don't know how to interpret that. I need help in interpreting the sentence. Could it be rephrased as:

> Newspapers across the political spectrum went into outrage mode as it should be.

That has a similar meaning to 1. above?

Comment: More like meaning 2 - they were expected to go into outrage mode and, as expected, they did.

Comment: Instead of "Newspapers ... as it should be" I suggest "Predictably, newspapers ... went into outrage mode."

Comment: @Peter I thought the meaning 2 means only time like 'in due time' or 'at the expected time'. So is it fine to use it in a way that I use 'as expected'?

Comment: Cambridge https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/duly includes "as expected".

Comment: @Peter Thank you for clearing up!